# How can I add 'Save', 'Copy', and 'Paste' in Tkinter Notepad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, save, tkinter-entry

I am learning (Tkinter)Python.
I want to add 'Save', 'Copy', and 'Paste' functionalities in my tkinter app called 'Notepad'
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os


window=Tk()

window.title("Simple Notepad")

def save():
    if t1_value.get() == "":
        t1.insert(END, "Please add text to save it")
    else:
        t1_value.get().save("New-file-1.txt")


t1_value=StringVar()
t1=Text(window)
t1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=6,padx=7,pady=7)

b1=Button(window,text="Close",width=15,command=window.destroy)
b1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=7,pady=7)

b2=Button(window,text="Copy",width=15)
b2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=7,pady=7)

b3=Button(window,text="Paste",width=15)
b3.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=7,pady=7)

b4=Button(window,text="Save",width=15,command=save)
b4.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=7,pady=7)

window.mainloop()
```

**"Save" function from above isn't working !**

Please tell me the method to add these above functionalities to this simple Tkinter notepad!

Comment: `t1_value.get()` returns a string.  Strings don't have a `save` method.  Use `open("New-file-1.txt","w").write( t1_value.get() + "\n" )`.

Comment: I am getting an empty file. I am not getting `t1_value.get()` in the txt document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make Notepad what can load and save. right?
I think use the `write` , `read`  and `with` function is more better for you.
First, you have to check the filename and then definition the save and open function

```
filename='mynote.txt'

def open_file():
    if os.path.isfile(filename) :
        with open('mynote.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as mynote_read:
            t1.delete('1.0',END) 
            t1.insert(END, mynote_read.read())
            t1.see(END)
def save_file():
    with open('mynote.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as mynote_write:
        mynote_write.write(t1.get('1.0',END))

        t1.delete('1.0',END)
        mynote_write.close()
```

Comment: I think you have to make sure the filename in your code. Use this code and then tell me what you want to know

Comment: This code works but I am limited to `filename='mynote.txt'`. How can I open any text file or save it with any name?

Comment: Ah, It's not pretty hard. Just change the filename. like ```filename =Simple_notepad.txt``` And plus, Change the code from ```with open('mynote.txt', blah blah......)``` to ```with open(filename, blah blah......)```. Then, It still work if you change to the any filename.

Comment: Ok, but what about copy and paste functionalities?

Comment: well.... that's own your task. I can talk about how to do that. But aren't you studying python now? then you have to think about how to do that and type that. And then,if you still don't know how to do. Come again and Ask. It's more helpful for your studying

Comment: No no you're getting me wrong I am learning it from a course(Self-taught). I didn't go to college for now. But thanks I will try to do it myself .

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyperclip library to copy and paste from clipboard.

```
import pyperclip as cb
.
.
button = tk.Button(root, text='Copy',
                      command=lambda: cb.copy(field['text']))
.
.
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error that 'field' is not defined. How can I solve that?

Comment: "field" here I meant your input field. Here you are using StringVar so directly do cb.copy(t1_value)

Comment: I am getting errors. It cannot copy the `StringVar()``Exception in Tkinter callback
pyperclip.PyperclipException: only str, int, float, and bool values can be copied to the clipboard, not StringVar`This is not the full error this the main line of the error.